# Reading file seperated by white spaces into dynamic array C++

Tags: c++

Hi I will read from file and put the numbers which is seperated with white space int different array.
Example file to read

```
15
10 2
20 1
30 1
```

This is what I did

```
    while(!file.eof()){ 
        file>>first[count++];

    }
```

By doing this I taking line by line but I want to read until white space and put the number after whitespace into different array.
As a result array will look like this (assume first and second are dynamic integer arrays)

```
first={15,10,20,30}
second ={0,2,1,1}
```

Comment: Note this Q&A: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) You should fix this 1st.

Comment: no I just put 15 into one array and since there is no number after space I will put the 0 to second array.

Comment: You can either run it once just to increment `count`, then allocate the array, rewind the file and run it again (this time saving the values into the array)... Or you can simply use a `vector`.

Comment: @barakmanos thanks but using vector is not allowed

Comment: Then use the first option

Answer (score 1):

You should use [string streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

```
#include <sstream>
...

string line;
while(getline(file, line))
{
   istringstream iss(line);
   int firstNumOnLine, secondNumOnLine.
   iss >> firstNumOnLine;
   first.push_back(firstNumOnLine);
   if(iss >> secondNumOnLine)
   {
        //... 
        second.push_back(secondNumOnLine)
   }
   else
   {
       //... there was no second number on the line.
       second.push_back(0);
   }
}
```

Here, `first` and `second` are assumed to be vectors

Comment: thanks but using vector is not allowed. I should use dynamic arrays

Comment: @mxyz: Then do `first[count++] = x;` instead of `first.push_back(x);`